# Cluster Analysis using pvclust in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, pvclust

I want to do cluster analysis of certain columns (variables), say var 5-var10. For that I used `pvclust` in R. Now, I want to add this column of clusters into the actual dataframe. Can anybody please help me to fix this problem. The code I used is given below:

```
group <- sqldf("select cq14x1_1,cq14x1_2,cq14x1_3,cq14x1_4,cq14x1_5,cq14x1_6,cq14x1_7, from parma_1")
fit_1 <- pvclust(group,method.hclust="ward",method.dist="euclidean")
group_2 <- (fit_1,alpha=.90)
```

Comment: Reading the help files for `pvclust` in package `pvclust`, it seems to me that `pvclust` calculates the p-values for clustering.  The underlying clustering is actually done using `hclust`.  See `?hclust` and its examples for help on how to do hierarchical cluster analysis.

Comment: -1 for using sqldf for stuff which can be made trivially and way faster using base R ;-)

Comment: I use sqldf as I'm more comfortable using sql queries. I don't know how could you put negative marking for somebodies preference?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is adding a column to a dataframe, just use:

```
yourdataframe <- cbind(yourdataframe, newcolumn)
```

If that's not your problem, try clarifying the question.

Comment: Actually I want to add the column that is defining the new cluster into the main dataset. And I was using the cbind option. But unfortunately it's ging error.                                  newdataset = cbind(group, group_2)                                  Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 199, 0

Comment: @user697363: well... you're not assigning anything to `group2` you put some parentheses in the code but you're not calling any function... so it has length 0 and you cannot `cbind` it to the data frame.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to rectify this problem. I want to add a new column in the present dataset, where the new column contains the clusters from pvclust. I can do it using hclust. But as I mentioned above I want to use pvclust rather than hclust.

Comment: The culprit is `group_2 <- (fit_1,alpha=.90)`... I'm not sure what that's supposed to do... I never used `pvclust`, but maybe you want to check the result of `str(fit_1)`. I assume `fit_1` will contain information about clusters.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the `pvclust` function is an object which contains an `hclust` element (check out section [Value](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pvclust/pvclust.pdf)). The `hclust` is basically a tree representation of the clustering (described [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/hclust.html)), and can be fed further into the `cutree` function which produces group memeberships. Have a look at the doc [page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/cutree.html) of `cutree`. You need these 3 functions to produce actual cluster memberships of your original data which can then be easily added to your dataframe as @nico suggested.

Comment: Glad to help. Let us know if this solves your problem and/or throws new issues.